# Lock Screen Recording In Privacy (System Preferences)

Tags: macos, system-settings, privacy, screen-recording

I made a standard account to try to put a password to system preference. When I go to privacy, everything is locked except "Screen Recording". I can change "screen recording" without having to unlock with the admin password. Anyone know why that is? And how to fix that? I would want the standard account not to be able to change anything in system preference

Answer (score 1):

Some settings in System Preferences are shared among all users (same for everyone), and some only affect the currently logged in user (each user can customize). The Screen Recording panel only affects the currently logged in user, so the standard account isn't affecting settings for anyone else.

To really restrict a user from Screen Recording, you can do this:

1. Open System Preferences...
2. Screen Time
3. Content & Privacy
4. Apps
5. Disable Screen Recording

Or just set an App Limit for System Preferences so that it can't be used at all.